# How do I use a variable after a transform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using unity so this is all unity

For example if I have
`string direction = left;`

I want to do
`transform.left;` as
`transform.direction;`

It throws an error when I do this cause transforms font have direction as one of those things after the dot.

Comment: What is `left`? What is `transform`? what is `transform.left`? ... You need to provide more context.

Comment: Sorry. This is all part of unity. I'm a beginner so these descriptions may be wrong. I transforms store the value of the position and rotation of objects. transform.left returns a vector of I believe(1,0). I want to replace the .left with a variable.

Comment: NVM I figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Vector3` for `direction` and you can just use `transform.TransformDirection` for this:

```
Vector3 direction = Vector3.left;
Vector3 worldDirection = transform.TransformDirection(direction);
```